# ggplot aes fill for continous values is always in blue?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is the code:

```
ggplot() + geom_col(data = s, aes(x = V1, y = V3, fill = V3, alpha = 0.5), show.legend = F) + coord_flip()
```

V1 is a series of names, while V3 is a series of numbers. So the output image is like this:

[image]

Everything is perfect, the only problem is I want the fill color to be in the green range, not blue.

Comment: Study the documentation regarding scales for fill colors.

Comment: @Roland Roland I've studied all the documentation and did all I could for the past 5 hours, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Use `scale_fill_gradient` and choose "green" colors for `low=` and `high=`. You need to choose the colors yourself if you don't want to use the default. There's no way just to change the hue

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks a looooot Flick, that actually worked! :)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want something that works nicely out of the box you can use `scale_fill_distiller` with `palette = "Greens"` or `palette = "YlGn"`

```r
set.seed(1)
s <- data.frame(V1 = LETTERS[1:20], V3 = runif(20, 0.2, 0.3))

ggplot(s) +
  geom_col(aes(x = V1, y = V3, fill = V3), alpha = 0.6) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = 'Greens')
```

[image]